# Laravel Storage for Amazon S3 'put' method uses wrong URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, storage

I am developing an app using Laravel 5.7 and currently trying to implement image storage using Amazon S3. I am using the `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` package with Laravel's built in Storage facade. When I try to upload an image, the `Storage->put()` command is generating the wrong URL.

I have followed multiple tutorials and docs online and all of them just use the following command

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('{file_name}', '{file_content}')
```

and the file_name is automatically prefixed with the amazon s3 url; however, for me this is not the case. But if I hardcode in the `AWS_URL`, everything works fine. I have all the correct values set up in the .env file (I believe) but Laravel seems to not be getting the `AWS_URL` correctly.

I have tried it with and without quotes around the env values. I have also ran

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

to clear the env variables' cache.

.env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="**************"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="****************"
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
AWS_BUCKET="*****"
AWS_URL=http://******.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

filesystems.php

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],
```

Using `php artisan tinker`:

This uploads the file properly, but I shouldn't need to hard code the url.

```
>>> Storage::disk('s3')->put('snoflow.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Hello.txt', 'Hello World!');
=> true`
```

This is how the command should be called but is giving an error. Notice the attempted Url is only the filename.

```
>>> Storage::disk('s3')->put('Hello.txt', 'Hello World!');
=> Aws/S3/Exception/S3Exception with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://filename.txt"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: filename.txt (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by removing the `AWS_URL` key in the .env.

Comment: I just want to add that AWS_URL should look like: `https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, it looks like AWS HTTP not properly built. And solve by modify .env

Before:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*****
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*****
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=*****
AWS_BUCKET=*****
AWS_URL=
AWS_ENDPOINT=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
```

After:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*****
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*****
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=*****
AWS_BUCKET=*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `.env` to only use following variables as mentioned on this [article](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-amazon-s3-file-upload-tutorialexample.html) worked for me:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*****
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*****
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=*****
AWS_BUCKET=*****
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
```